# How to bind a progress bar to a listbox through curselection()

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

See the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
    
# Creating Listbox

list = Listbox(window, selectmode = "multiple", font = ("Consolas", 21), width=100, cursor='dot')

# Inserting items in Listbox

list.insert(0, 'activity1')
list.insert(1, 'activity2')
list.insert(2, 'activity3')
list.insert(3, 'activity4')
    
list.pack()
    
def go(event):
    list = event.widget   
    progressbar.set(len(list.curselection())) 
    
progressbar = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(master=window, width=100, height=20, border_width=5)
progressbar.pack()
progressbar.bind('<<Listbox>>', go)
```

I want the above-mentioned code to move the progress bar every time an item is clicked in the listbox. it doesn't move at all

Comment: It is not clear what you mean *"move the progress bar every time an item is clicked in the listbox"*.

Comment: Also you need to bind `<<ListboxSelect>>` on the listbox, not the progressbar.  Better not use `list` as a variable name because it is a keyword in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day all,
I've managed to solve the issue of connecting the progress bar to the listbox.
The issue was mainly the function...

```
def go(event):
    list = event.widget    
    if progressbar['value'] < int(list.size()) - 1:
        progressbar['value'] = len(list.curselection())       
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Well done!!", message="You've completed all the tasks!")
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(window, length=200, mode='determinate', maximum=int(list.size()))
progressbar.pack()

list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', go)
```

Thanks again and all the best!!

Answer (score 2):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def go(event):
   selected_items = list.curselection()
   progressbar['value'] += len(selected_items)

window = Tk()
list = Listbox(window, selectmode="multiple", font=("Consolas", 21),
width=100, cursor='dot')
list.insert(0, 'activity1')
list.insert(1, 'activity2')
list.insert(2, 'activity3')
list.insert(3, 'activity4')
list.pack()

progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(window, length=100, mode='determinate')
progressbar.pack()

list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', go)

window.mainloop()
```

- Changed `progressbar.set(len(selected_items))` to `progressbar['value'] += len(selected_items)`. This sets the value of the progress bar to the number of selected items.
- Added `mode='determinate'` when creating the progress bar. This sets the mode of the progress bar to determinate, which allows you to set the value manually.

Comment: Srrry my bad  I have editted the code . i missed `+` in `progressbar['value'] += len(selected_items)`, you can also set relative values as well to move the progress bar more by given more value to `progressbar['value']`.

Comment: Now it works fine. This was just a demonstration, if  `mode=determinate`, you must measure relative progress, instead of  adding `len(selected_items)`  you can set relative value like +25 but before adding use if to check  `progressbar['value']` not greater than 100.

Comment: Thank you, and all the best!! just one problem, the progress bar fills long before I click everything

Comment: progress bar not working properly, the progress bar fills long before I click everything and it does not decrease when I deselect the item. please assist. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code:

- need to bind `<<ListboxSelect>>` on the listbox widget instead of the progressbar
- `CTkProgressBar.set()` accepts values from 0 to 1
- better not use `list` as variable name because it is a keyword in Python

Below is the updated code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter

window = customtkinter.CTk()

# Creating Listbox
listbox = tk.Listbox(window, selectmode="multiple", font=("Consolas", 21), width=100, cursor='dot')
listbox.pack()

# Inserting items in Listbox
listbox.insert(0, 'activity1')
listbox.insert(1, 'activity2')
listbox.insert(2, 'activity3')
listbox.insert(3, 'activity4')

def go(event):
    listbox = event.widget
    if listbox.size() > 0:
        progressbar.set(len(listbox.curselection())/listbox.size())

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', go)

progressbar = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(master=window, width=100, height=20, border_width=5)
progressbar.pack()
progressbar.set(0)

window.mainloop()
```